# Export buttons Datatable

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, datatable, datatables

I need to group in a single drop-down `button` to put export buttons as in this example:[enter link description here](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/extensions/exportButtons.html)

This in my current `Project` :

```js
var table = $('#listaDocumentos').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'
    ],
    language: {
        "decimal": "",
        "emptyTable": "No hay información",
        "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Documentos",
        "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Documentos",
        "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
        "infoPostFix": "",
        "thousands": ",",
        "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Documentos",
        "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
        "processing": "Procesando...",
        "search": "Buscar:",
        "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
        "paginate": {
            "first": "Primero",
            "last": "Ultimo",
            "next": "Siguiente",
            "previous": "Anterior"
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"> <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>

<table id="listaDocumentos" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Donna Snider</td>
            <td>Customer Support</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/01/25</td>
            <td>$112,000</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put Export buttons in the drop-down you can use the following code.
while initializing a data table you can use the following code to display the button with a collection of buttons.

```
buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'collection',
                    text: 'Export',
                    buttons: [
                        'copy',
                        'excel',
                        'csv',
                        'pdf',
                        'print'
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

you must use the script following order

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.7/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src=" https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.4/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.4/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#listaDocumentos').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'collection',
                    text: 'Export',
                    buttons: [
                        'copy',
                        'excel',
                        'csv',
                        'pdf',
                        'print'
                    ]
                }
            ],
            language: {
                "decimal": "",
                "emptyTable": "No hay información",
                "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Documentos",
                "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Documentos",
                "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
                "infoPostFix": "",
                "thousands": ",",
                "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Documentos",
                "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                "processing": "Procesando...",
                "search": "Buscar:",
                "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
                "paginate": {
                    "first": "Primero",
                    "last": "Ultimo",
                    "next": "Siguiente",
                    "previous": "Anterior"
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: you can give a demonstration, because the truth did not work

Comment: Also, you can get here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cgrTzr2lzw2JyS2a9aKJb0u33IjCo23z/view?usp=sharing